# Clickonce Publish page suddenly disabled 'Updates' button

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clickonce

The 'Updates' button on the publish tab of my project has suddenly disabled.  I have been doing an update every couple of weeks for more than a year, and it has been working very well.  I use the 'Updates' button to change the minimum required version.

I have tried running as administrator and rebooting.  I don't believe any settings have changed since our last update (which was a few days ago).

Does anyone have any idea why this might suddenly disable?  Is there another way to change the minimum version?

In case it helps, this code is stand alone (ie: no code repository), using Visual Studio 2008, Visual Basic.  The machine is Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out.  I must have accidentally changed the Install Mode and Settings to be available 'online only'.  When online only, the Updates button is disabled.

I noticed this by restoring from a backup and comparing the settings.  Glad to get it back - hope this helps someone else sometime.